# WebServices working on windows and not working on android

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I implemented this simple webservice example:
[Creating and Consuming Soap Services in Delphi.](http://chapmanworld.com/2015/03/30/creating-and-consuming-soap-services-in-delphi/) I added a multi-device application to the example.
It works well on then windows platform, it also works well on the Samsung S6 edge Browser.
But it crashes executing the android app.

Here's the server side code:

```
TMyService = class(TInvokableClass, IMyService)
  public
    function HelloWorld : String; stdcall;
end;
...
function TMyService.HelloWorld: String;
begin
  Result := 'HelloWorld';
end;
```

Here's the client side code

```
procedure TForm3.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Service: IMyService;
begin
  // capture interface to service
  Service := unitIMyService.GetIMyService();
  edit1.Text := Service.HelloWorld;  // It crashes here
  ...
end;
```

Is there any error or am I missing something on the android side?

Comment: did you check the permissions?

Comment: The permissions on the server side are ok. Are there any permissions on the android?

Comment: Go to Menu Project \ Options, select "Target Android Plataform" and in left menu select Uses Permissions and select "Access network state" and "Access wifi state"

Comment: They were unchecked, I Checked them but it continues to crash.

Comment: try to catch the exception

Comment: I tried to catch the exception but it crashes before showing it.

Comment: I gave up trying to use SOAP on android.

Comment: I'm using REST following this example and its working. https://delphisolutions.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/rest-webservice-em-delphi-com-indy-sem-datasnap/